# Update particular grid cell in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I have very simple example in Python:

```
class Solution(object):

    def grid(self, m, n):
        grid = [[0] * n] * m
        grid[0][0] = 1
        print(grid)


Solution().grid(5, 3)
```

When I run this code, it prints `[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]`

I'd expect it'd print `[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]`

I'm running **Python 3.8.5**

What am I missing here?

Comment: Use a list comprehension `grid = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]` or numpy `grid = numpy.zeros((m, n))`